# Opening my app when some other app is opened

Tags: java, android

I want to open my app when some other app is opened.
Ex:
I want to open my game launcher when some game is opened and i want to draw over the other app

How can i make this in android studio? If you found any online article or videos attach the link down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified of the execution of other applications, you must use [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService), by activating AccessibilityService, your app will be notified whenever a application is executed, this is the simplest and best solution for that.

You can also get permission [Appear on top](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNkCXUOh1Cw) to draw on other apps or start an activity from your app instead of drawing, there is currently no other control solution.